# Jquery Datatables extend settings and functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm not an expert in JQuery so this question may be applied to plugins other than DataTables. Suppose I want to declare an additional(custom) setting in the initialisation:

```
var dTable = $('#example').DataTable(
    ...,
    'myOption' : [{ 'text' : 'Foo' } , { 'text' : 'Bar' }, ...],
)
```

and if myOption is declared, i want to automatically call a function like this one(like a callback function):

```
function() {
    console.log(dTable.settings().myOption)
}
```

so basically, i want to extend a plugin but i do not understand how it can be done from the manuals or other examples.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is quite easy to achieve what you want. Hook into the `init.dt` event and with some closure magic you have a "plugin" :

```js
//myOption "plugin"
(function() {
  var run = function(myOptionSettings) {
    console.log(myOptionSettings)  
  };
  $(document).on('init.dt', function (e, settings, json) {
    var myOption = settings.oInit.myOption || false;
    if (myOption) {
      run(myOption)
    }
  })
})(document);
```

In use :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  myOption : [{ 'text' : 'Foo' }, { 'text' : 'Bar' }]
})
```

demo ->  **http://jsfiddle.net/e3vyjta5/**